# Short Form of Global Constants in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, constants

I created a constants.php file in config folder.

A part of my constants.php file is

```
return [
    'contact' => [
         'phone'  => '--phone---'
         'phone2' => '--phone2--'
    ]
    'company' => [
         'title' => '--company--'
    ]
    'url'  => '--url---'
]
```

I'am using config() method to call this constants.

```
config('constants.company.title')
config('constants.url')
```

Before using laravel i'm using php constants

```
COMPANY_TITLE
URL
```

Writing code like this is not good i think. I hate repeating `constants.` Is there any short way to use our own constants in Laravel 5.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
config('constants.company.title')
```

is not constant, this is configuration data. You can use constants like:

```
COMPANY_TITLE
URL
```

because laravel is php and you can use normaly php constant syntax.

Comment: i know it is configuration files. These my own constants for configuration of my web app. Ok if i can use COMPANY_TITLE, where should i define it to call in every where (blade, controller, models etc.)